# Laravel is it correct to set up a Model to get data from SQL's views?

Tags: database, model-view-controller, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Imagine I have my DB structure with tables A, B, C ... N
Tables have their relations. Nothing new...

Could it be a good a idea to set up a model that implement a group of methods to retrieve views of my DB (related to a concept e.g. statistics). So this model will not be directly connected to a real table, but it is a bunch of query joins on 2 or more tables...(with subqueries to other tables), or calls to stored func/procedures SQL views...

Or it is more stylish to stick to classical model setup, so have a model for each table and place around these models my (stats) methods ?

Or Maybe in laravel5 there's some functionality/sw-layer to implement this kind of cross tables non standard complex queries?

An example of query may look like :

```
SELECT 
    id_quote, h, AVG(numquote)
FROM
    (SELECT 
        id_quote, COUNT(*) numquote, HOUR(datetime) h
    FROM
        MyDB.A
    WHERE
        id_quote IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY DATE(datetime) , HOUR(datetime)) AS C
GROUP BY id_quote , h;
```

Comment: could you edit your question and add both structures your referring to? your question is not very clear

Comment: I'm still in a project /analysis phase, I don't have yet a real idea of the DB structure. Anyway I'm adding a query example that may be useful to understand my concern.

Comment: I wouldn't use a model because Eloquent comes loaded with a ton of stuff that you won't be able to use, and don't want to be tempted to use by mistake. Eloquent objects take up a lot of memory so it's a waste to use them when all you're doing is fetching from a view. Just my opinion, curious to see what others say

Comment: Eloquent performance issues on complex queries might also deserve to be considered. But I'm more interested here on how to implement, in a LRVL5 MVC pattern, the model. Until now I just placed the Raw query in the controller to pass data to the view. But I believe it has to be moved to a model stage ( the retrieve & preparation of the data) even if this is not strictly connected to DB structure. Because here we are considering a view, i.e.  data representation.